# Site exists with Access violation when adding Google authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, google-oauth

I'm trying to add google authentication and have installed the nuget oacjage **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google** v. 7.0.14

But when I try to add it to services, the site stop with message

> The program '[20972] LT.LoveMatch.Natural.exe' has exited with code
> 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Code:

```
GoogleConfigSection config = new GoogleConfigSection();
builder.Configuration.GetSection("Google").Bind(config);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(opt =>
{
    opt.ClientId = config.ClientId;
    opt.ClientSecret = config.ClientSecret;
});
```

Just created a new website project and did nothing but install nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google 8.0.3 and added the service. It worked before I added the service, then it failed with code Access violation.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(opt => {
    opt.ClientId = "clientId";
    opt.ClientSecret = "secret";
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please share more details about your Program.cs file.

Comment: Any solution about this?

Comment: No not yet. Do you also experience the same issues?

Comment: It's better to provide a brand new sample project which could reproduce the issue for us. Then we can help you check it.